# python sort list

Tags: python

short of renaming/fixing the logging module on the webservers...   when i do a list.sort(), the list entries get placed in the following order:

```
2011-09-21 19:15:54,731 DEBUG __main__ 44: running www.site.com-110731.log.0.gz
2011-09-21 19:15:54,731 DEBUG __main__ 44: running www.site.com-110731.log.1.gz
2011-09-21 19:15:54,731 DEBUG __main__ 44: running www.site.com-110731.log.2.gz
2011-09-21 19:15:54,732 DEBUG __main__ 44: running www.site.com-110731.log.3.gz
2011-09-21 19:15:54,732 DEBUG __main__ 44: running www.site.com-110731.log.gz
```

how would i sort a list, to get (ie the entry eithout a digit to be first):

```
2011-09-21 19:15:54,732 DEBUG __main__ 44: running www.site.com-110731.log.gz
2011-09-21 19:15:54,731 DEBUG __main__ 44: running www.site.com-110731.log.0.gz
2011-09-21 19:15:54,731 DEBUG __main__ 44: running www.site.com-110731.log.1.gz
2011-09-21 19:15:54,731 DEBUG __main__ 44: running www.site.com-110731.log.2.gz
2011-09-21 19:15:54,732 DEBUG __main__ 44: running www.site.com-110731.log.3.gz
```

THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would probably want to write a custom comparator to pass to `sort`; in fact, you probably need to anyway, because you're likely getting a lexicographical sort order instead of the intended (I presume) numerical order.

For instance, if you know that the filenames will only differ in those digits, you'd write a comparator that extracts those digits, converts them to `int`, and then compares based on that value.

Taking your examples as canonical, your comparator might look something like this:

```
import re
def extract(s):
    r = re.compile(r'\.(\d+)\.log\.((\d*)\.)?gz')
    m = r.search(s)
    file = int(m.group(1))
    if not m.group(2):
        return (file, -1)
    index = int(m.group(3))
    return (file, index)

def comparator(s1, s2): return cmp(extract(s1), extract(s2))
```

This prefers to sort based on the "file" number (the first one), and then by the "index" number (the second one).  Note that it takes advantage of the fact that using `cmp` on tuples works as we require.

Comment: well...  i know the 110701.log.gz always would be first, then the .log.1.gz .log.2.gz , etc

Comment: This is a bit off the cuff, but seems to work as you seem to intend.  You should compile the regular expression outside of `extract` if this is "serious business".

Comment: would `l.sort(key=extract)` work, as `sort`'s `cmp=` is deprecated?

Comment: Yes, it should work exactly the same; I didn't realize it was deprecated in Python 3, so that's good to know.

Comment: Guys, i must admit, this is a bit over my head... trying to learn :)  should i pass the list to the comparator function?  should i split up the logfile names myself, then pass them?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: I imagine that this means that the string you are trying to sort doesn't match the regular expression (and so `m` is `None`); you'll need to adjust the expression if the filenames vary at all from what I've assumed.